# citeproc-lua for individual CSL style? Need help on setup

Tags: bibliographies, citing, bibliographystyle, pandoc-citeproc

my university has its own (I know stupid) ciation style, for which they provide a csl file to be used with zotero.
Does anyone have similar regulations to follow at their university and maybe could provide some help or work-around?

I came across: https://github.com/zepinglee/citeproc-lua but am not too experienced with LaTex, just enjoy learning it bit by bit.

This is my uni's csl file https://www.zotero.org/styles/universitatsmedizin-gottingen

Help would be highly appreciated!!

EDIT3 (for the solution below with removed duplicates): Produces the following error.

[image]

> /Library/TeX/texbin/lualatex -file-line-error -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 these.tex

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022) restricted system commands enabled. (./these.tex LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1 L3 programming layer <2022-02-24> (./MastersDoctoralThesis.cls Document Class: MastersDoctoralThesis (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls Document Class: book 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk11.clo)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/luababel.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/luababel.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/american.ldf (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile-hook.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlogo.sty))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrhack.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xpatch/xpatch.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/setspace/setspace.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/setspace.hak) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translations/translations.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/ltcaption.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/x11nam.def)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlayer-scrpage.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlayer.sty)) 1: chapter 1: chapter 1: section ) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty

Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/framed/framed.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.cfg)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hluatex.def (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/stringenc.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/nth/nth.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/float.hak (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/minipage-marginpar/minipage-marginpar.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/multicol.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/enumerate.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/arydshln/arydshln.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdflscape/pdflscape.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/lscape.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/lscape.hak)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/afterpage.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfplots/pgfplotstable.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.revision.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.revision.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-luatex.def (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotscore.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgfplotssysgeneric.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/pgfplotslibrary.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_loader.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryfpu.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/luamath/pgflibraryluamath.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsutil.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsliststructure.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsliststructureext.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsarray.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsmatrix.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/numtable/pgfplotstableshared.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsdeque.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsbinary.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsbinary.data.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsutil.verb.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/pgflibrarypgfplots.surfshading.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgflibrarypgfplots.surfshading.pgfsys-luatex.def))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotscolormap.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotscolor.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsstackedplots.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsplothandlers.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsmeshplothandler.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsmeshplotimage.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.scaling.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotscoordprocessing.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.errorbars.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.markers.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsticks.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.paths.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduledecorations.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgflibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgflibrarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/tikzlibrarypgfplots.contourlua.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplotmarks.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/numtable/pgfplotstable.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/numtable/pgfplotstable.coltype.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.meta.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/subcaption.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/placeins/placeins.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/pgflibrarypgfplots.colorbrewer.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/tikzlibrarycolorbrewer.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/citation-style-language/citation-style-language.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook-2020.sty)))

./these.tex:205: LaTeX Error: Command \bibfont undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type H for immediate help. ...

l.205 \renewcommand*{\bibfont} {\scriptsize} (./these.aux (./Chapters/Chapter1.aux)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translations/translations-basic-dictionary-english.trsl) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii [Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).] ) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg)) geometry driver: auto-detecting geometry detected driver: luatex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty)) (./these.out) (./these.out) Package pgfplots notification 'compat/show suggested version=true': you might benefit from \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} (current compat level: 1.7).

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): (hyperref) removing `math shift' on input line 221.

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): (hyperref) removing `\alpha' on input line 221.

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): (hyperref) removing `math shift' on input line 221.

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): (hyperref) removing `math shift' on input line 221.

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): (hyperref) removing `\beta' on input line 221.

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): (hyperref) removing `math shift' on input line 221.

1: section [1{/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}<./Figures//Logo.png>] [2]

Declaration of Authorship

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 283--284

1: section [3] [4]

Abstract

1: section [5] [6]

Acknowledgements

1: section [7] [8] (./these.toc) 1: section [9] [10] (./these.lof) 1: section [11] [12] (./these.lot) 1: section [13] [14] 1: section [15] [16]

Dedicatory

1: section [17] [18] 1: section (./Chapters/Chapter1.tex Chapter 1. 1: section [1]

LaTeX Warning: h' float specifier changed to ht'.

./Chapters/Chapter1.tex:51: Undefined control sequence. ...0; Emamzadeh 2016; Lautenschl{\textbackslasha }ger et al. 2018) l.51 ...h2016alpha,bartels2010n,lautenschlager2018c} . Importantly, the C-termi... ./Chapters/Chapter1.tex:53: Undefined control sequence. l.53 ...settings \cite{svensson2015vagotomy}. \cites {kordower2008lewy} investi... ./Chapters/Chapter1.tex:53: Undefined control sequence. l.53 ...om host tissue to the graft. Further, \cites {luk2012intracerebral} sho... ./Chapters/Chapter1.tex:53: Undefined control sequence. l.53 ...s came to full circle when a study by \cites {kim2019transneuronal} rev... ./Chapters/Chapter1.tex:72: Undefined control sequence. l.72 ...tasis and vesicular cycling. In fact, \cites {giguere2019increased} ind... [2] [3<./Figures/Aetiology.png>] [4 Missing character: There is no ‚Äô (U+2019) in font ec-lmr10! <./Figures/synucleins.png>] [5]

LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `fig:Mitochondria' on page 6 undefined on input line 82.

./Chapters/Chapter1.tex:91: Undefined control sequence. (Tol{\textbackslasho } et al. 2018) l.91 ...tive value \cite{tolo2018pathophysiological} .\

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 78--93

[6] ./Chapters/Chapter1.tex:108: Undefined control sequence. l.108 ...di2007non}. Furthermore, research by \cites {liddelow2017neurotoxic} c... ./Chapters/Chapter1.tex:112: Undefined control sequence. (Lindstr{\textbackslasho }m et al. 2017; Rostami et al. 2017) l.112 ...te{lindstrom2017extensive,rostami2017human} . Nonetheless, astrocytes ... ./Chapters/Chapter1.tex:114: Undefined control sequence. l.114 .... Moreover, 6-OHDA lesion studies by \cites {kuter2019increased} ident... ./Chapters/Chapter1.tex:114: Undefined control sequence. ...ovic 2008; Schlaudraff and Sp{\textbackslasho }rkel 2014) l.114 ...ankovic2008parkinson,schlaudraff2014morbus} .\ [7] [8 Missing character: There is no ‚Äô (U+2019) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äô (U+2019) in font ec-lmr10! ] ./Chapters/Chapter1.tex:151: Undefined control sequence. l.151 ...poradic disease, however research by \cites {polymeropoulos1997mutatio...

LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `fig:Genes' on page 9 undefined on input line 151.

./Chapters/Chapter1.tex:151: Undefined control sequence. l.151 ...r, $\alpha$-syn proteomic studies by \cites {sulzer2017t} identified t... ./Chapters/Chapter1.tex:167: Undefined control sequence. l.167 ...in ligase, respectively. Research by \cites {matheoud2016parkinson} in... [9] [10] ./Chapters/Chapter1.tex:235: Undefined control sequence. l.235 ...epidemiological clinical research by \cites {li2012subsequent} investi... [11 Missing character: There is no ‚Äô (U+2019) in font ec-lmr10! ] [12<./Figures/Immunity.png>] [13]

LaTeX Warning: h' float specifier changed to ht'.

./Chapters/Chapter1.tex:264: Undefined control sequence. l.264 ...2004cytokines}. Moreover, a study by \cites {jangula2013lipopolysaccha... ./Chapters/Chapter1.tex:264: Undefined control sequence. l.264 ...e with the latter, a recent study by \cites {dohgu2019monomeric} expos... ./Chapters/Chapter1.tex:265: Undefined control sequence. l.265 Next, post-mortem research by \cites {gray2015striatal} pointed towards B... ./Chapters/Chapter1.tex:265: Undefined control sequence. l.265 ... any other brain area. For instance, \cites {chen2009severe} have show... ./Chapters/Chapter1.tex:266: Undefined control sequence. (Erd{\textbackslashH {o}} et al. 2017) l.266 ...eimer's disease, and PD \cite{erdHo2017age} . In addition, ageing is n... ./Chapters/Chapter1.tex:266: Undefined control sequence. l.266 ...ou2008altered}. Notably, research by \cites {vincent2008functional} di... ./Chapters/Chapter1.tex:267: Undefined control sequence. l.267 ...oimmunity. Specifically, research by \cites {louveau2018cns} using the... [14] [15<./Figures//BBB.png>] [16]

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): (hyperref) removing `math shift' on input line 269.

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): (hyperref) removing `\alpha' on input line 269.

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): (hyperref) removing `math shift' on input line 269.

LaTeX Warning: h' float specifier changed to ht'.

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 321--331

[17]) [18<./Figures//SNARE.png>] [19] [20] ./these.tex:470: Undefined control sequence. l.37 ... Calopa M, Mestre M, Mollev{\textbackslashi } DG, Cutillas B, Ambrosi... l.470 \printbibliography

1: section [21 Missing character: There is no ‚Äô (U+2019) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äì (U+2013) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äô (U+2019) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äì (U+2013) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äì (U+2013) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äì (U+2013) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äô (U+2019) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äì (U+2013) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äì (U+2013) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äì (U+2013) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äì (U+2013) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äì (U+2013) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äô (U+2019) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äì (U+2013) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äì (U+2013) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äì (U+2013) in font ec-lmr10! ] ./these.tex:470: Undefined control sequence. l.55 ..., Pakkenberg B, Pedersen L {\textbackslashO }stergaard (2017): Autoim... l.470 \printbibliography

./these.tex:470: Undefined control sequence. l.61 ..., Buchman V, Etherton MR, S{\textbackslashu }dhof TC (2010): alpha-sy... l.470 \printbibliography

Underfull \hbox (badness 1067) in paragraph at lines 73--74 []\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 Chaud-huri KR, Schapira AH (2009): Non-motor symp-toms of parkin-son‚Äôs dis-ease: [22 Missing character: There is no ‚Äô (U+2019) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äô (U+2019) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äì (U+2013) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äô (U+2019) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äì (U+2013) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äò (U+2018) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äô (U+2019) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äì (U+2013) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äô (U+2019) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äì (U+2013) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äì (U+2013) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äô (U+2019) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äì (U+2013) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äô (U+2019) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äì (U+2013) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äì (U+2013) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äô (U+2019) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äì (U+2013) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äô (U+2019) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äì (U+2013) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äô (U+2019) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äì (U+2013) in font ec-lmr10! Missing character: There is no ‚Äì (U+2013) in font ec-lmr10! ] ./these.tex:470: Undefined control sequence. l.124 Erd{\textbackslashH {o}} F, Denes L, de Lange E (2017): Age-associate... l.470 \printbibliography

./these.tex:470: Undefined control sequence. l.127 ...to A, Dohm CP, Kermer P, B{\textbackslasha }hr M, Wouters FS (2007):... l.470 \printbibliography
```

-> Continues like this

Comment: maybe try to remove the `\addbibresource{examples.json}` line. It seems to produce an error.

Comment: Okay, that works for your example.bib in your tex example. But if I run it without json in my .tex it doesn't work and it also does not work if I use my thesis bibliography.bib in your example tex. Could there by something wrong with my bibliography bibtex? 

and many thanks for your help I cannot empahsize enough how life saving this is :D

EDIT: I updated the error/screenshot for the problem

Comment: the error says that there is duplicate `koch2015alpha` entry in your bib file. Try to rename one of them. But it seems like a bug that it causes compilation error.

Comment: I'll go through my .bib again and remove other duplicates as well. But you'd think that overall I'd have to wait for the package to mature?
EDIT: So removing all duplicates actually made it typeset, however, it generates a range of errors which are UTF8 related I guess. Basically every non englisch letter is not typesetted. (will update above)

Comment: It seems that `citeproc-lua` expects BIB file to be in the UTF_8 encoding, while you have LaTeX commands like `\'o` in your bib file. Fortunately, you can convert  your bib file to the correct format using the `biber --tool --output-format=bibtex -O new.bib examples.bib` command (use suitable names for the bib files)

Comment: Thank you :) could you explain me where to place that code in order for it to work? :)

Comment: It needs to be done from the command line. Or you can send me your bib file, and I will try to correct it. You can find my mail here: https://github.com/michal-h21

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that styles that are not built-in can be referenced by their filename without extension. So copy the file `universitatsmedizin-gottingen.csl` to the directory with your TeX file, and then you can use something like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{citation-style-language}
\cslsetup{style = universitatsmedizin-gottingen}
\addbibresource{examples.bib}
\addbibresource{examples.json}

\begin{document}

\cite{texbook,latex2e,ITEM-1}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

It uses two databases, one is traditional BibTeX file, `examples.bib`:

```
@book{texbook,
  author = {Donald E. Knuth},
  year = {1986},
  title = {The {TeX} Book},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley Professional}
}

@book{latex:companion,
  author = {Frank Mittelbach and Michel Gossens
            and Johannes Braams and David Carlisle
            and Chris Rowley},
  year = {2004},
  title = {The {LaTeX} Companion},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley Professional},
  edition = {2}
}

@book{latex2e,
  author = {Leslie Lamport},
  year = {1994},
  title = {{LaTeX}: a Document Preparation System},
  publisher = {Addison Wesley},
  address = {Massachusetts},
  edition = {2}
}

@article{knuth:1984,
  title={Literate Programming},
  author={Donald E. Knuth},
  journal={The Computer Journal},
  volume={27},
  number={2},
  pages={97--111},
  year={1984},
  publisher={Oxford University Press}
}

@inproceedings{lesk:1977,
  title={Computer Typesetting of Technical Journals on {UNIX}},
  author={Michael Lesk and Brian Kernighan},
  booktitle={Proceedings of American Federation of
             Information Processing Societies: 1977
             National Computer Conference},
  pages={879--888},
  year={1977},
  address={Dallas, Texas}
}
```

Other possibility is to use CSL JSON, like this `examples.json`:

```
[
    {
        "author": [
            {
                "family": "D’Arcus",
                "given": "Bruce"
            }
        ],
        "citation-key": "ITEM-1",
        "id": "ITEM-1",
        "issued": {
            "date-parts": [
                [
                    2005,
                    11,
                    22
                ]
            ]
        },
        "note": "The apostrophe in Bruce’s name appears in proper typeset form.",
        "publisher": "Routledge",
        "title": "Boundaries of dissent: Protest and state power in the media age",
        "type": "book"
    },
    {
        "author": [
            {
                "family": "Bennett",
                "given": "Frank G.",
                "suffix": "Jr."
            }
        ],
        "citation-key": "ITEM-2",
        "container-title": "Pac. Rim L. & Pol’y J.",
        "id": "ITEM-2",
        "issued": {
            "date-parts": [
                [
                    2009,
                    8
                ]
            ]
        },
        "page": "463-509",
        "title": "Getting property right: “informal” mortgages in the Japanese courts",
        "type": "article-journal",
        "volume": "18"
    },
    {
        "author": [
            {
                "family": "Lamport",
                "given": "Leslie"
            }
        ],
        "citation-key": "ITEM-3",
        "edition": "2",
        "id": "ITEM-3",
        "issued": {
            "date-parts": [
                [
                    1994
                ]
            ]
        },
        "publisher": "Addison-Wesley",
        "publisher-place": "Reading, MA, USA",
        "title": "LaTeX: A document preparation system: User’s guide and reference manual",
        "type": "book"
    },
    {
        "author": [
            {
                "family": "Mittelbach",
                "given": "Frank"
            },
            {
                "family": "Goossens",
                "given": "Michel"
            },
            {
                "family": "Braams",
                "given": "Johannes"
            },
            {
                "family": "Carlisle",
                "given": "David"
            },
            {
                "family": "Rowley",
                "given": "Chris"
            }
        ],
        "citation-key": "ITEM-4",
        "edition": "2",
        "id": "ITEM-4",
        "issued": {
            "date-parts": [
                [
                    2004
                ]
            ]
        },
        "publisher": "Addison-Wesley",
        "publisher-place": "Reading, MA, USA",
        "title": "The LaTeX companion",
        "type": "book"
    }
]
```

It produces the following result with `lualatex`:

[image]

Comment: I think the OP uses Zotero, so maybe they are interested in using a csl-json database. Maybe you will want to add this line as well: `\addbibresource{example.json}`?

Comment: @Denis sure, but I don'ŧ have any example of csl-json unfortunately.

Comment: it's all in there: https://github.com/zepinglee/citeproc-lua/tree/main/example

Comment: @Denis thanks, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment. Adding the above to my tex. produces the following error (! LaTeX Error: File `citation-style-language.sty' not found.). Is there anything else to adopt?

Comment: @poebelchen do you use up-to-date TeX distribution? It should be part of TeX Live 2022

Comment: I am using Texpad v.1.9.9 (OS), currently no update uption :( Or is the the mactex that should be updated? EDIT: I will download MacTex and see if that helps :) thanks a lot so far :)

Comment: @poebelchen yes, you need to updated MacTeX, as it is the distro with packages.

Comment: @poebelchen it supports only `\cite` and `\cites` commands. You can see the documentation here: https://texdoc.org/serve/citation-style-language/0

Comment: unfortunately, it does not seem to work for me. It produces a lot of "csl-core.lua", "csl-lua" and "direct-lua" errors

Comment: @poebelchen that's unfortunate to hear. it is still a young package, so it can have some issues. do you get these errors on my example, or on your own files? could you update your question with the error messages?

Comment: also with your example, one second.

Comment: @poebelchen I was getting a lot of errors to. After saving the style in the same directly, it works!

Answer (score 1):

A bug report is always welcome at https://github.com/zepinglee/citeproc-lua/issues. It would be appreciated if you provide the full example that reproduce the errors.

From the output log, I can only provide the following suggestions.

1. The CSL-JOSN format is preferred over the .bib format. The former is used in the internal of citeproc-lua as well as Unicode. The .bib database needs to be converted to CSL-JSON before processing. Unfortunately the current implementation of this converter is rather naive and it can't handle the conversion from `\"o` to Unicode. I'll try to implement this conversion in the next couple of weeks and can you provide the .bib file for testing? In general, if you use Zotero for maintaining the bibliographies, it's more convenient to export the items directly in CSL-JSON format so the conversion procedure can be skipped.
2. The correct way to set the font in bibliography is `\cslsetup{bib-font = \scriptsize}` rather than `\renewcommand*{\bibfont}`. The latter is used in `natbib` and `biblatex` packages. It is necessary to add the traditional `\bibfont` interface? I generally prefer the key-value interface in many modern packages like `siunitx`.